# How to resolve missing @ rb_readlink for brewlinux?

Tags: ruby, linux, homebrew, package-managers

I am attempting to get brewlinux up and running as a package manager on a server in which I have no other package managers available or admin privileges.

The installation seemed to go ok however I am unable to download any packages and receive the following warning:

> : warning: pthread_create failed for timer: Operation not permitted, scheduling broken
>   /var/sites/d/x.com/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/current/bin/ruby: No such file or directory @ rb_readlink - /proc/self/exe (Errno::ENOENT)

When I run `$ brew doctor` I also get that message likewise when I just type `$ brew` however `$ brew update` seemed to work and now says already up to date.

It seems a file (or maybe more) are missing however I am unsure why and how to resolve this can anyone help please?

My .bashrc looks like the following:

> export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
>
> export LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH"
>
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
>
> export CPATH="$HOME/include:$CPATH"
>
> export HOMEBREW_PREFIX="$HOME/.linuxbrew"
>
> export PATH="$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/bin:$PATH"
>
> export LIBRARY_PATH="$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH"
>
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
>
> export
>   CPATH="$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/include:$CPATH"

Ruby version is 1.8.5
Python version is 2.4.3

Please note I have been trying to follow the steps in the following guide https://blog.eduardovalle.com/2015/10/15/installing-software-without-root/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to repeat the obvious, but first try to resolve any other problems with the brew mantra:

1. `brew update`
2. `brew update` #(yes again!)
3. `brew doctor`

and follow ALL recommendations of brew doctor.

---

Apparently you did this, so next is to tell brew to use less threads:

- `HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS=1 brew doctor`

and follow ALL recommendations of brew doctor.

---

If this helps, run

- `echo "export HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS=1 >> ~/.bashrc"`

Or pipe to other rc file (.profile or .bash_profile or ...), in case you are running a different shell.

---

Please note: The brewing will be slower, but it should work now. However, if you feel like playing try:

- `HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS=2 brew doctor`
  or
- `HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS=4 brew doctor`

---

Happy brewing :-)